# argparse update choices of an argument

Tags: python, argparse

Using argparse, is there any way to update the "choices" option of an argument  after it was added to the parser ? [Argparse documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#choices) doesn't yield much about updating the choices

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

choices_list = ['A', 'B']
parser.add_argument('arg1', choices=choices_list)

# The list of choices now changes 
choices_list = ['A', 'C', 'D']

# Some code to update 'arg1' choices option ?
parser.???
```

I tried using 'parser.add_argument' with the new 'choices_list', but it creates duplicate arguments.

Using Python 3.7

Comment: Is there a reason you don't build a completely new parser when this happens? If it's built by a function, you can just feed the things that can change in as arguments.

Comment: Unless you are using the parser multiple times (perhaps calling `parse_known_args`, and updating `choices_list` before calling it or `parse_args` again), it would probably be simpler to just defer adding the argument until you know the final value of `choices_list`. Argument parsers are typically pretty static, being fully defined before you actually do any sort of I/O.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy There is no reason I can't build a new parser. I only felt it was cleaner to modify an attribute than recreating a completely new object.

Comment: @chepner Maybe I'm not using the right tool for this, but I have an interactive shell (with cmd2) and the choices of some options are dependent of previous actions. I do not know in advance what I'll have to show, but I need to have some kind of default choices when the interactive shell starts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument itself has a `choices` attribute, but it's easiest if you save a reference to the argument instead of trying to retrieve it from the parser itself. (Otherwise, you have to scan through the private attribute `parser._actions` and try to identify which one you need.)

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

choices_list = ['A', 'B']
arg1 = parser.add_argument('arg1', choices=choices_list)

arg1.choices = ['A', 'B', 'D']
```

Comment: I confirm it does work, but using pycharm, a weak warning is triggered -> "Function 'add_argument' doesn't return anything". In argparse.pyi, I can see that "add_argument" expects no return value. Any idea why it was documented like that?

Comment: No idea. One could make the argument that you shouldn't rely on `add_argument` returning anything because it's not documented, but it doesn't seem likely that it would ever change.

Comment: The fact that `add_argument` returns an `Action` object isn't in the documentation, but then a lot of details aren't documented.  But it is obvious from the code, and obvious when `argparse` is tested in an interactive session.  `argparse` documentation is more of a how-to document than a formal specification.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/2and3/argparse.pyi

```
# undocumented
class _ActionsContainer:

    def add_argument(self,
                 ...
                 **kwargs: Any) -> Action: ...

    def add_argument_group(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> _ArgumentGroup: ...
```

I don't use `pycharm`, but I'm puzzled as to why it would complain about `add_argument`, but not about `add_argument_group`.

The argparse docs doesn't mention the returned `Action` object, but that's because users don't usually need to access it.  But when tested interactively it's pretty obvious:

```
In [93]: import argparse
In [94]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [95]: parser.add_argument('--foo', choices=['one','two'])
Out[95]: _StoreAction(option_strings=['--foo'], dest='foo', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=['one', 'two'], help=None, metavar=None)
In [96]: _.choices
Out[96]: ['one', 'two']
```

Previous SO answers have pointed out that the `Actions` are also available in 'hidden' `_actions` list.  But in Python, that '_' is just an informal convention; the interpreter doesn't enforce privacy.

```
In [98]: parser._actions
Out[98]: 
[_HelpAction(option_strings=['-h', '--help'], dest='help', nargs=0, const=None, default='==SUPPRESS==', type=None, choices=None, help='show this help message and exit', metavar=None),
 _StoreAction(option_strings=['--foo'], dest='foo', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=['one', 'two'], help=None, metavar=None)]
```

What's displayed is the string representation of the `Action` object.  Those are the most commonly used attributes.

The documentation for `argparse` is not a formal API reference; it's too incomplete for that.  It's more of a advanced how-to document, more involved than a tutorial, but not as complete as a formal specification.

Comment: for some reason, I've got a different `argparse.pyi` [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/VsLFH6DT). Looking at line 79, I understand that PyCharm expects no return value, but I don't understand why this `-> None # weirdly documented` for `add_argument` was added in the first place